# Linux Laptop USB-C charging no longer working

Tags: linux, laptop, charging

I Have an HP Envy x360 with a AMD Ryzen 3 2300U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx.

edit: after further experimentation, it seems that the hardware is cycling the charger when below 100%. Tested by powering down the laptop and comparing the charge light between barrel charger and usb-c.

Keeping this here in case anyone has any insight to this problem.

I recently bought a USB-C charger and one of these 5-in-1 hubs:
https://alogic.co/nz/catalog/product/view/_ignore_category/1/id/6951/s/usb-c-fusion-core-5-in-1-hub-v2/

Everything has been working fine until today when it now cycles the charger and anything else plugged into the hub stops working. The setup works with my work laptop still.

/***** now, potentially irrelevant notes *****/

`udevadm monitor` yields:

```
KERNEL[449.016211] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:34/PNP0C09:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ADP1 (power_supply)
UDEV  [449.034566] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:34/PNP0C09:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ADP1 (power_supply)
KERNEL[449.320248] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:34/PNP0C09:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ADP1 (power_supply)
UDEV  [449.344547] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:34/PNP0C09:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ADP1 (power_supply)
```

I have also tried downgrading the following packages that were upgraded recently:

```
linux-firmware (20230117.7e4f0ed-1 -> 20230210.bf4115c-1)
amd-ucode (20230117.7e4f0ed-1 -> 20230210.bf4115c-1)
manjaro-release (22.0.4-1 -> 22.0.5-1)
```

When the USB-C power connector  is connected to the hub `dmsg -w` yields:

```
[  258.202161] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.P004.PPCV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[  258.202182] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SBRG.EC0._Q2B due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[  258.542381] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.P004.PPCV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[  258.542399] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SBRG.EC0._Q2B due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[  258.742182] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.P004.PPCV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[  258.742202] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SBRG.EC0._Q2B due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[  258.965497] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.P004.PPCV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[  258.965516] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.SBRG.EC0._Q2B due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
```

But this does not occur when plugging the USB-C charger in directly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you manage to solve this? I have the same issue on an Asus BR1100C.

Comment: Hi, @aafirvida it turned out to be a bit in the firmware, as it happens on windows/Linux and powered down. Updated the firmware to the latest but the problem persists. Basically have up on it. Maybe try updating your firmware but other than that 

Comment: Update for any future lurkers. I have solved the problem. Only relevant to those who have a HP Envy x360 with a AMD Ryzen 3 2300U. It turns out the laptop will no charge correctly if it is in a vertical position. I have just bought a vertical stand and it turns out that was the problem. I have a feeling it might have something to do with the screen being cracked as there may be some orientation hardware behind the screen for tablet mode, that affect power delivery. I will forward onto HP regardless. @aafirvida. 